# C++ error A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, static

I am trying to call a function on an object, but I'm getting this error. I have two classes: a Sudoku class and a Puzzle class. The Sudoku class inherits the Puzzle class. The Sudoku class has protected variable, a 2D array of Puzzle objects `Puzzle libraryOfPuzzles[4][10];` When I try to call the setSolution function on a the `libraryOfPuzzles[][];` , it doesn't work. However, when I call it on a `Puzzle test[4][10];` that is created inside the function itself, it works. Why is this?

```
void Sudoku::createLibraries(string name) {
    Puzzle test[4][10]; //added for demonstration purposes
    string fileName = "";
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
        fileName = name + to_string(k) + ".txt";
        string aWord;
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open(fileName);
        i = 0;
        int value = 0;
        while (!fin.eof()) {
            fin >> aWord;
            int value = stringToInt(aWord);
            libraryOfPuzzles[k / 10][k % 10].setSolution(i / 9, i % 9, value); //this line gives error
            test[k / 10][k % 10].setSolution(i / 9, i % 9, value); //this line is fine
            i++;
        }
    fin.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Include the full error message in your question, and show how you declare `libraryOfPuzzles`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createLibraries cannot be defined as static.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you! Why can't createLibraries be defined as static?

Comment: Because `libraryOfPuzzles` is a non-static member variable so to access it you need a valid `this` pointer,  which static methods do not have.  The error message from the compiler could be a little less cryptic but this is pretty elementary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that you array is not public. So libraryOfPuzzles[][]; can't access it but Puzzle test[4][10]; can.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I changed it to public but same problem.